# How can I make the slides in my jQuery slideshow fade smoothly?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I've been looking at a tutorial for a simple jQuery slideshow on this website - https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/zKbYzP

I've tried to adapt it slightly so that instead of adding the images with HTML, I can add the images with CSS through the `background-image` rule. This has worked, but I've lost the smooth fade transition as the slides transition into one another. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Here's my jsFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/71pfnkcm/1/

**HTML**

```
<div id="slideshow">
   <div id="slide-one" class="slide">
   </div>
   <div id="slide-two" class="slide">
   </div>
   <div id="slide-three" class="slide">
   </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
}

#slideshow { 
  margin: 50px auto; 
  position: relative; 
  height: 100%; 
  padding: 10px; 
}

.slide {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: 100%;
}

#slide-one {
  background-image: url("https://www.kimballstock.com/images/animal-stock-photos/new-stock-photos.jpg");  
}

#slide-two {
  background-image: url("https://www.kimballstock.com/images/animal-stock-photos/wildlife-stock-photos.jpg");
}

#slide-three {
  background-image: url("https://www.kimballstock.com/images/animal-stock-photos/farm-animal-images.jpg");  
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

setInterval(function() { 
  $('#slideshow > div:first')
    .fadeOut(2000)
    .next()
    .fadeIn(2000)
    .end()
    .appendTo('#slideshow');
},  4000);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem's because you're missing the `position: absolute` for the `.slide`

Because you're using a `div` which default style is a `block` element, when you normally add 3 `div` together, it will just stack from top to bottom, and when you animate it on a slideshow, the `div` is shown first before it's animated to `0%` or `100%` opacity which makes the slideshow doesn't work as smoothly as you want

Therefore you need to use the `position: absolute` to the `.slide` element so that it will exit the current element flow, and positioned relative to it's nearest relative parent, which is why the `div#slideshow` is styled `position: relative`

Here's the updated snippet

```js
$("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

setInterval(function() { 
  $('#slideshow > div:first')
    .fadeOut(2000)
    .next()
    .fadeIn(2000)
    .end()
    .appendTo('#slideshow');
},  4000);
```

```css
html {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
}

#slideshow { 
    margin: 50px auto; 
    position: relative; 
    height: 100%; 
    padding: 10px; 
}

.slide {
  position: absolute; /* this is what you're missing*/
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: 100%;
}

#slide-one {
  background-image: url("https://www.kimballstock.com/images/animal-stock-photos/new-stock-photos.jpg");  
}

#slide-two {
  background-image: url("https://www.kimballstock.com/images/animal-stock-photos/wildlife-stock-photos.jpg");
}

#slide-three {
  background-image: url("https://www.kimballstock.com/images/animal-stock-photos/farm-animal-images.jpg");  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slideshow">
   <div id="slide-one" class="slide">
   </div>
   <div id="slide-two" class="slide">
   </div>
   <div id="slide-three" class="slide">
   </div>
</div>
```

You can also learn more about the `position` style from this [article](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/position/)